Отрезать голову буферу в stringstream
stringstream buff наполняется через buff.rdbuf()->sputn(data, len)
потом делаются операции
...tellg
...getline
...seekg
после seekg то что находится перед указателем g мне не нужно - надо освободить эту память. А указательp должен писать данные там где остановился.

Если смотреть на эту илюстрацию, то переместить put begin pointer и get begin pointer на get next pointer и освободить память.
Есть идея вырезать кусок между g и p в новый буфер, удалять старый буфер и заменить его новым, потом выставить указатели на начало и конец... но это совсем не потокобезопасно.

А какая именно задача решается? Выглядит так, как будто вам нужен связный список, нодами которого будут буферы фиксированного размера (какого - зависит от задачи и данных). Память для нод выделяет/освобождает кастомный аллокатор на заранее выделенном куске памяти. Но все манипуляции со списком все равно должны быть синхронизированы.

Для однобайтовых ячеек связный список громоздок. С синхронизацией мне проще написать на си. Цель - понять нужны ли мне плюсы.

Ячейки можно сделать хоть по килобайту, хоть больше. Зависит только от темпа поступления новых данных в буфер.

их клеить потом... сделал на си через memmove. надеялся что есть высокоуровневое апи к этому
